# Create/update a sub-object in the Django admin edit dialog

Tags: django, django-admin

I'd like to create/update a "sub-object" within an admin edit dialog.

I have a "CmsObject" model, which contains several "CmsPageItem" objects (currently there will be just one fixed CmsPageItem, but that will change in the future). Rather then letting a `StackedInline` widget control the layout, I would like to display *one* additional textarea field somewhere in the `change_form.html` page.

What would the recommended approach to extend the ModelAdmin dialog be?
I expect I need to push a formfield somewhere, or introduce new values in the template context?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by sub-object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've eventually settled to implement the whole view myself. For most simple objects, implementing the inlines (either with a custom template, or without) is good enough. In this situation I require more control, so I've overwritten the entire `add_view` and `change_view` completely.

FeinCMS also does this for it's editor window.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at TabularInlines? There is an example here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/

Comment: I've seen it, but that's not something I'm looking for. I'd like to have more control over the positioning then a TabularInline gives me.

Comment: Then you will have to edit the template and/or the formsets. Django-cms has a similar kind of model layout. You could check out how they implement this.